# select button ng model value undefined inside ng if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i have a problem,i cant get value from ng-model inside ng-if. if i alert the model the result is undefined. here is my html file

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="yayaya">
                <option value="1">yeyeyeye</option>

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" ng-if="yayaya ==='1'">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="yoyoyo">
                <option value="bla">blabla</option>
                        </select>
        </div>
```

this is the result when i alert the ng-model
[image: when i alert($scope.yayaya);][image: when i alert($scope.yoyoyo);]

Comment: it works fine, what is the issue

Comment: i got udefined result if i alert($scope.yoyoyo);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ng-change to get the model value, you can pass it as follows,

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.show = function(yo) {
      alert(yo);
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<div class="col-sm-2">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="yayaya">
                <option value="1">yeyeyeye</option>

            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2" ng-if="yayaya ==='1'">
            <select ng-change="show(yoyoyo)" class="form-control" ng-model="yoyoyo">
                <option value="bla">blabla</option>
            </select>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i want to pass the value to query param. what should i do?

Comment: assign to a variable and use the value

Comment: like this ? 
`var yee = $scope.show 
         yee = function(ye) {
            alert(ye);
        };`

Comment: you should assign inside the funciton